# db2 on cloud rollforward and incremental backup

Tags: dashdb

I want to restore the backup and do roll forward in db2 on cloud.How I can achieve this?
I am able to do full backup restore but I want to restore to end of logs.I did't see rollforward option in db2 on cloud

Comment: Which toolset are you using? Which exact cloud offering are you using? Have you studied the documentation, for example https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-bnr#point-in-time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.